# Addon or Replace strapi existing rich text editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, strapi

There is a CKEditor which is implemented well with Strapi Version3 but not able to setup with Version4 of Strapi.

Is it possible to implement in version4 or can I addon extra components setup with version4 in existing rich text editor ?

Here is the implementation with [strapi version 3](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi)